# Can you define the <iframe> src attribute in css?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Can you define an iframe's src attribute in css as opposed to in the  html tag? Is there a fundamental reason why this wouldn't work?

I wanted to clean up my HTML a little bit by moving a long source link out of the main page but couldn't find an answer to this anywhere.

Comment: No, you can't. CSS is supposed to define style, not contents.

Comment: @AlexShesterov You can define text content wih css.

Comment: @Hacketo, but you should use it for styling only, e.g. adding a colon after `dt` elements. Definitely *not* for adding significant content.

Comment: "I wanted to clean up my HTML a little bit by moving a long source link out of the main page" Doing so by CSS is definitely not the correct way. I believe "template includes" are more relevant to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work because `src` has nothing to do with rendering style.